# Jenkins container: Groovy script fails with jbdc exception

Tags: oracle, jdbc, containers, classpath, jenkins-groovy

I have a job in Jenkins (Jenkins is running from a container) which uses a groovy script with the line:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql;
def driver = "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
```

when running it, I'm getting the exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource

I know what is the root cause, but don't know how to fix it.
The root cause is that all our Jenkins containers are installed without Oracle, and ojdbc7.jar can be found in the java classpath under Oracle:

```
classpath /oravl01/oracle/12.1.0.1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc7.jar
```

in regular Jenkins server, it runs without any issues.
any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did 2 things:
1. copied the file ojdbc7.jar to the path mentioned in java.ext.dirs (in illinXXX:XXX/systemInfo)
2. Ran the docker run command with --env classpath=[path of ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar]